# Qt how to present and edit data across tables

Tags: sql, qt, view, model

Please bear with me as this is a slightly subjective matter but I'm after informed best practice for what is likely a common situation.

I have data split out into multiple (sqlite) tables which I am using Qt to manipulate. A (sql) view is one way to show data from multiple tables, but I wish to be able to update values as well.
Let's take a three table example, using say houses. 
The three tables are linked via foreign keys, say an Area table, a House table, and a Furniture table. There's a 1:many relationship linked with foreign keys: Area:House, House:Furniture
I would like to have a UI item with Areas populate a House UI item which in turn populates a Furniture UI item. By UI item, I mean something like an editable list, or series of lineEdits/Spinners (value type dependant), anything really.

just to clarify a bit, i understand about how to use qsqlrelationaltablemodel and qsqlrelationdelegate. These work fine when I'm updating a single table, but won't update a (sql) view created from joins on multiple tables.
I'm after a solution that lets me efficiently work on data from multiple tables, including updating the values.

Should I do this with three models, updating the filter on each, and using a view linked to each model? 
Or perhaps I could insert everything into a single tree model? 
Or should I be looking at creating a custom model, or perhaps just not using model/view and manually populating UI?

I have tried using multiple models on the same database as an experiment a while ago, and they didn't behave together as nicely as I'd hoped. This is the main reason I'm asking about best practice.

Much appreciation for any advice you can offer.

Comment: Your model seems ok, typical relational model - but are you asking how to update one table based on IDs from another?

Comment: Have you looked into QSqlRelationalTableModel? I'm not exactly sure what you mean by one table UI populating another table populating another. Perhaps you could clarify with more specifics in your example? Between the Relational model and Delegates in your views that might get you what you are looking for. But again, that's a guess base don what I *think* you are saying.

Comment: Hi. @M.R nope I get how to update on table based on ids from another.

Comment: @the real bill, thanks but I understand about qsqlrelationaltablemodel. i'll edit the question to be a bit clearer. sorry all for the confusion

Comment: So then, can you explain your question a little bit more? because in my experience, updating all the tables separately (in transaction) leads to better data integrity, better maintenance, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I guess my question wasn't as clear as it could be; namely because I didn't really know the right question to ask.
I was looking for a way to represent data from multiple tables over separate UI items, in a way that didn't necessarily map directly to a tableview.

My solution so far is to use separate models, populated from the database manually. Any editing of the values that is required I am doing manually.

Seems to work ok so far.
One handy tip I've picked up is putting extra data in a different role Qt::UserRole. This was I can store pertinent UUIDS (my db keys are all UUIDs) with data in a single column treeview, and use these to get fairly direct db access. Extra data can apparently be put in Qt::UserRole+n, although I haven't tried that yet.